# Inverse of $f: \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \to \mathbb{Z}_{210}$ such that $f(a,b)= 10a +21b$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \to \mathbb{Z}_{210}$ such that $$f(a,b)= 10a +21b.$$

We have that $f$ is an *isomorphism*, but how does one go about finding *explicitly* the inverse $f^{-1}$ of $f$?

Comment: $$10[a]+21[b]\cong[1] mod(210)$$ since 10 and 21 are prime to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a homomorphism (say, $h$) from a *cyclic* group $< a >$ (i.e, a group generated by the element $a$) to some group $G$, all we have to do is to assign an appropriate image of $a$ (i.e, we will assign some value to $h(a) \in G$ appropriately).

Since the group $\mathbb{Z}_{210}$ is generated by $1$, to find $f^{-1}$, all we have to do is to assign an appropriate element to $f^{-1}(1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21}\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Since $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, to assign a value for $f^{-1}(1)$, all we have to do is to find which element in $\mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ that $f$ maps to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{210}$, then assign $f^{-1}(1)$ to be that element, and the element we're talking about is $(19, 1)$. This element can be easily found by noticing the fact that: $(-2) \times 10 + 1 \times 21 = 1$, and the element $-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$ is the same as the element $19$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$.

So $f^{-1}: \mathbb{Z}_{210} \to \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is constructed so that $f^{-1}(1) = (19, 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, so, take any element $c \in \mathbb{Z}_{210}$, we'll have:

$$f^{-1}(c) = f^{-1}(\underbrace{1 + 1 + ... + 1}_{c \text{ elements } 1'\text{s}}) = \underbrace{f^{-1}(1) + f^{-1}(1) + ... + f^{-1}(1)}_{c \text{ elements } f^{-1}(1)'\text{s}} = (19c; c)$$

Comment: $f^{-1}$, and $f$ are just inverses of each other, so it's the same as you are given $f$, and trying to find $f^{-1}$; and to do so, it totally depends on the problem. In this particular problem, since you are constructing a homomorphism from a cyclic group, it's easier, because all you need is to construct the image of the generator (this is what I'm trying to say in the first paragraph of my answer). You can read my reply again, in order to have a deeper understand of what I say.

Comment: I claim that $\mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is cyclic, can you find its generator?

Comment: I know I've to find an element of period 210, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: That's a good start; now just think simply, can you find an element $(a; b) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, such that the smallest positive number $n$ satisfying $(na; nb) = (0; 0) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ must be 210? Note that $x = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{21}$ means that $x$ is divisible by 21; and $y = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ means that $y$ is divisible by 10. I repeat, "think simply".

Comment: Does it suffice that $a$ is not divisible by $21$ and $b$ is not divisible by $10$?

Comment: Not quite. Here's a counter-example: 3 is not divisible by 21; and 2 is not divisible by 10; but $(3; 2)$ is only of order (or, as you call it, period) 35; since $(35 \times 3; 35 \times 2) = (105; 70) = (0; 0) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Comment: Well, $(1,1)$ should do the trick.

Comment: So far, so good. So $\mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is generated by $(1; 1)$; and you are trying to construct a homomorphism $g^{-1}: \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10} \to \mathbb{Z}_{210}$, all you have to do is to assign a value for $g^{-1}(1; 1)$. Now, using the definition for $g$ above, i.e $g(x) = (19x; x)$. Can you find the element $d \in \mathbb{Z}_{210}$, such that $g(d) = (1; 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$? Or put it this way, can you find $d$ such that $19d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 21$; and $d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 10$?

Comment: Yes, $31$ works.

Comment: Great, so we'll assign $g^{-1}(1; 1) = 31 \in \mathbb{Z}_{210}$; and since $(1; 1)$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, every element in $\mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ can be expressed as $(c; c)$ (for some appropriate $c$, of course); so the homomorphism you are looking for is $g^{-1}(c; c) = 31c \in \mathbb{Z}_{210}$. This is a little bit hard to see that $g^{-1}$ and the original $f$ are the same; but in fact, they are.

Comment: And how does one get back $g(a,b) = 10a + 21b$ from that?

Comment: You don't really need to get back to that, there are many ways to define just one mapping. But if you really want to do it, for every $(a; b) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, can you find a $c$, such that $(a; b) = (c; c) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$?

Comment: I'll try that. Another thing: is the generator of $G \times H$ the couple of the generators of $G$ and $H$?

Comment: No, in general, it does not hold. There are groups, such that $G$, and $H$ are both cyclic, but not $G \times H$ ($\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is an example). The other way does hold however, i.e if $(a; b)$ is the generator of $G \times H$, then $a$ must be the generator of $G$, and $b$ must be the generator of $H$.

Comment: You can work from (1; 1) onwards, like this: $(1; 1) = (1; 1)$; $(2; 2) = (2; 2)$; $(3; 3) = (3; 3)$; ...; $(10; 10) = (10; 0) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$; $(11; 11) = (11; 1)$; $(12; 12) = (12; 2)$; ...; $(21; 21) = (0; 1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{21} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}; (22; 22) = (1; 2)$; ... You'll find out that $(21; 21) = (0; 1)$, and $(190; 190) = (1; 0)$; hence $(a; b) = a(1; 0) + b(0; 1) = a(190; 190) + b(21; 21) = (190a + 21b; 190a + 21b)$. From here, I think it should be easy for you to prove the similarity between $g^{-1}$; and $f$. Hopefully you can go from here, right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for everything.

Answer (score 4):

Since both are cyclic, both have a generator. You need only find $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b)=1$, which amounts to the division algorithm. Then

$$f^{-1}(c) = (ca, cb)$$

In this case we have $a=19, b=1$.

Further explanation:

Suppose you have $f(a,b)=1$, i.e. $10a+21b=1$. If $g(c)=(ca,cb)$ then

\begin{align*}
g(f(x,y)) = g(10x+21y) &= ((10x+21y)a, (10x+21y)b)\\
&=  (10ax,21by)\\
&=  ((1-21b)x,(1-10a)y)\\
&=  (x,y)
\end{align*}

Comment: edited with more details

Comment: $21b \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb Z_{21}$. Yes it does, nothing was special about the $21,10$, just that they are coprime

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known, and easy to check, that if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, and $um+vn=1$ is  a *Bézout's relation* between $m$ and $n$ the inverse isomorphism from $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ to $\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z$ is given by
$$(x\bmod m,y\bmod n)\longmapsto yum+xvn\bmod mn.$$

Indeed $z=yum+xvn$ satisfies $$z\bmod m=xvn\bmod m=x(um+vn)\bmod m=x\cdot 1\bmod m=x\bmod m,$$
and similarly $\bmod n$.